# Analyze internet speed using java program

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I need a program that analyze the internet speed of the network.

Is possible to write such a program in Java?

Comment: Define what exactly you mean by "the internet speed". The question is too general to give useful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following article on JavaWorld will help you!

- [Java Tip 65: Measure data transfer speeds via Sun's ORB in JDK 1.2 beta 4](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip65.html)

and the following question on StackOverflow might also be useful.

- [How to detect Internet connection speed with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4127836/851432)